# Html href not opening link

Tags: html, css

I am making a portfolio page, which is going fine, except the uploading project link. This is the code I am working on (it's a free online template so cannot change much of the code)

```html
<article class="from-left">
  <a href="images/fulls/01.jpg" class="image fit">
    <img src="images/thumbs/01.jpg" title="Superstore project" alt="" />
   </a>
</article>
```

The issue is that when I replace the image with a link to a github page, nothing happens and the webpage goes into a loop type waiting image.

```html
 <article class="from-left">
  <a href="www.google.com" class="image fit">
    <img src="images/thumbs/01.jpg" title="Superstore project" alt="" />
  </a>
</article>
```

My HTML and CSS skills are very basic level, not sure what is the issue. What I want is that when I click a picture it opens up the link provided. Below is the free html template I am using

https://html5up.net/big-picture

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've read your template readme file and understood what is happening. The problem is that the template uses a component called *"[jquery.poptrox](https://github.com/ajlkn/jquery.poptrox)"*. This component makes the gallery links to open a popup with that picture.

To do what you want, find the file "main.js". Then look for *$gallery.poptrox*

You have to comment this entire block. It will be like this:

```js
//$gallery.poptrox({
//    baseZIndex: 10001,
//    useBodyOverflow: false,
//    usePopupEasyClose: false,
//    overlayColor: '#1f2328',
//    overlayOpacity: 0.65,
//    usePopupDefaultStyling: false,
//    usePopupCaption: true,
//    popupLoaderText: '',
//    windowMargin: 50,
//    usePopupNav: true
//});
```

Notice that I put a double slash to comment each line. This should disable that component and your links now will open what you want instead of opening a popup. You can also delete this block of code, but I don't know if you would like the original behaviour back in the future. So, it's up to you.

Important:

Your links should start with "*https://*". So, it'll be like this:

```html
<article class="from-left">
    <a href="https://www.google.com" class="image fit">
        <img src="images/thumbs/01.jpg" title="The Anonymous Red" alt="" />
    </a>
</article>
```

If you want your link to open in a new tab of the browser, add the *target="_blank"* attribute.

```html
<article class="from-left">
    <a href="https://www.google.com" target="_blank" class="image fit">
        <img src="images/thumbs/01.jpg" title="The Anonymous Red" alt="" />
    </a>
</article>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing "www.google.com" to "https://www.google.com", right now the link may be sending you to [your website]/www.google.com

Answer (score 0):

You can add `https://` in URL and `target="_blank"` so that the link will open in a new tab.

```html
<article class="from-left">
  <a href="https://www.google.com" target="_blank" class="image fit">
    <img src="images/thumbs/01.jpg" title="Superstore project" alt="Sample Image" />
  </a>
</article>
```

Here is link of [JSBin](https://jsbin.com/hepagofewo/edit?html)

Answer (score 0):

I know it's been marked as solved, but if I understood correctly there is an easier solution.

From the [Poptrox docs](https://github.com/ajlkn/jquery.poptrox), inside the anchor tag you can pass

```
data-poptrox="ignore"
```

and it will work as a normal anchor tag.

So in the case of OP

```html
<article class="from-left">
  <a
    href="images/fulls/01.jpg"
    class="image fit"
    data-poptrox="ignore" <!-- ADD THIS LINE -->
  >
    <img src="images/thumbs/01.jpg" title="Superstore project" alt="" />
   </a>
</article>
```